# Where can I find the .NET Framework 3.5 Entity Framework Sample application files that are described in the MSDN documentation?

Tags: entity-framework, sample

Where can I find the .NET Framework 3.5 Entity Framework Sample application files that are described in the MSDN documentation?

The download link in the [MSDN documenation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399293.aspx)  is a link to the Visual Studio 2008 SP1 download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [HRSkillsCombined.zip](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFDocSamples/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1516) file. It should contain both the windows app and the website.

It still lists it as the "VS2008 SP1" download, but the summary seems to be correct. I believe it was just mislabeled on this page.

Comment: I looked there but don't see a reference to the sample code.  Where is the code located?